# simplified boundary checking for Java List

Tags: java, optimization, list

Is there an easy way/library to check and adjust parameters to stay inside the lists boundaries?

Here a long sample:

```
if (fromIndex < 0) {
  fromIndex = 0;
}
if (fromIndex > list.size() - 1) {
  fromIndex = list.size() - 1;
}

if (toIndex < 0) {
  toIndex = 0;
}
if (toIndex > list.size() - 1) {
  toIndex = list.size() - 1;
}

list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
```

I know i could move `list.size() - 1` to a variable and do an extract-method on the index checks to remove redundant code. But it still seems a bit verbose for this simple task.

Answer (score 5):

```
public int sanitize(int index) {
  return Math.max(0, Math.min(index, this.length-1));
}
```

Comment: little note: `list` or `listSize` should also be a parameter

Comment: @tatilans: true, in the context of this snippet that looks a bit like a static method.  However Brian's suggestion to wrap an existing list is a much much better way to realise this (more flexible, less intrusive, less boilerplate code) and in that case `list` would likely be a final member field.

Comment: OK. I changed it to this.length. If it just adds more confusion I will roll back :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check *all* accesses to your list, it seems to me you want to wrap your list within a class implementing the [List](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface and intercept the accessor methods to check/modify the accessor indices.

e.g.

```
List sanitised = new SanitisedList(existingList);
```

This is an example of the [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern. Note how you just need one class defined (`SanitisedList`) and you can apply that to any list you have. Use [Zed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525266/simplified-boundary-checking-for-java-list/1525291#1525291) for a nice tidy bounds check.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ternary operator:

```
int listMax = list.size() - 1;
list.subList( fromIndex < 0 ? 0 : (fromIndex > listMax) ? listMax : fromIndex, 
              toIndex < 0 ? 0 : (toIndex > listMax) ? listMax : toIndex );
```